# TypeError: client.on is not a function (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I keep getting this error and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

`TypeError: client.on is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
const client = require("../index");

const { promisify } = require("util");

const wait = promisify(setTimeout);

const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")


let invites;

module.exports = {
  name: "setchannel",
  description: "Sets the channel.",
  async execute(message, args) {
    const channelids = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription("Please enter a channel or channel ID.")
      .setColor("#E74C3C");

    client.on("ready", () => {
        console.log("Ready!");
        client.user.setActivity("$help", { type: "PLAYING" }).catch(console.error);
        
        client.guilds.cache
        .get(message.guild.id, true)
        .fetchInvites()
        .then((inv) => {
          invites = inv;
        });
        
      });
```

This is in a separate file not my index.js file. I have declared
`const client = new Discord.Client();` in my index.js file but I am unsure of what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.on('ready')` is useless in this file. Firstly, you should use that in your index.js. Secondly, client was never defined in index.js as `module.exports`, therefore it is undefined. You can’t get expect JavaScript to just look through your files and get the client from there! Also, if you try `message.client.on('ready')`, it won’t throw an error, but it also won’t run anything, since it runs pretty much all at once, and the only way you get the message, is if the client was ready, and ready won’t be run twice. My solution is to just remove the `client.on` in that file.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of helped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `const client = require("../index");` does not actually reference the discord client instantiated in your index.js. You need to export the client in order for it to be accessible from another file.

In your index.js:

```
module.exports = {
    client
}
```

In your second file:

```
const { client } = require("../index");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep a note of this.